# Tasks Async/Await ... don't get it

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I have implemented multitasking in C# like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TasksAsyncAwait
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource
                = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            Task taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task 1 start");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine($"T1: {i}");
                    cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(500);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Task 1 complete");
            }, cancellationToken);

            Task taskTwo = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task 2 start");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine($"T2: {i}");
                    cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(300);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Task 2 complete");
            }, cancellationToken);

            Task.WaitAll(taskTwo, taskOne);
            Console.WriteLine("Program done.");
        }
    }
}
```

I was told that, though the code works perfectly and is easy to understand, it was outdated and deprecated and thus bad style, and that I need to rewrite this code to follow the async/await scheme. I read a lot about how to use async/await, a few tutorials do even cover how to do it in a console app, but frankly speaking I don't understand a word. Please show me how to convert my code into async/await style.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: I read what you linked, and there it says: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." My Q looks like a perfect fit to me.

Comment: _"My Q looks like a perfect fit to me"_ - you also said _"`though the code works perfectly..., it was outdated ....bad style, and that I need to rewrite this code`"_

Comment: @MickyD are you sure that questions about code improvement are off-topic on StackOverflow? Can't I ask (for example) how to modernize my code by switching from a `Hashtable` to a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, or from `foreach` loops to LINQ, or from long `if`/`else if` statements to pattern matching? Does the [*no actual problem to be solved*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) implies that having a hard time to understand the newer technologies is a fake problem that shouldn't be dealt with?

Comment: I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TasksAsyncAwait
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            Task taskOne = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task 1 start");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine($"T1: {i}");
                    await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Task 1 complete");
            }, cancellationToken);

            Task taskTwo = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task 2 start");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine($"T2: {i}");
                    await Task.Delay(300, cancellationToken);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Task 2 complete");
            }, cancellationToken);

            await Task.WhenAll(taskOne, taskTwo);
            Console.WriteLine("Program done.");
        }
    }
}
```

No blocking code; asynchronous waiting everywhere!